# how to get misclassification rate in each fold of cross validation?

Tags: matlab, cross-validation

I am currently using this syntax in matlab to get misclassification rate in 10-fold cross validation :

```
target = [repmat(1,ntrial,1);repmat(2,ntrial,1)];
cvo = cvpartition(target,'k',10);
func = @(XTRAIN,ytrain,XTEST)(classify(XTEST,XTRAIN,ytrain));
mcr = crossval('mcr',pooling,target,'predfun',func,'partition',cvo);
```

(where 'pooling' is the 2-class feature set I'd like to classify with the classifier)

From what I read, `mcr` will return the average misclassification rate from 10 folds. Now if I want to get the misclassification rate from *each* fold, what should I do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that in this case you would like to have a bit more control over the training/validation process. Have you considered breaking down the process for more control?
Start with `cvpartition` to create the 10-folds for cross validation and then act on each fold separately.

Comment: I have a bit of problem breaking down the `crossval` process because I don't quite get the concept of `cvpartition` function. I'm afraid if I make the partition by myself, will the 'stratified' property be violated?

Comment: @Neu, You may try and simulate the high-level functionality using the low-level functions and see if you get similar results...

Comment: I know this was asked a long time ago but it might help someone else to know that the indices of the cvpartition object can be accessed using the `training` and `test` functions. See docs here https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/cvpartition.training.html